# What does this link signifies inside script tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, server, server-side-rendering

I was inspecting element of a website then i stumbled upon this portion of code,
script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script

after browsing the url it opens up a uncomprehendable piece of JS code, i know this is naive que, but i just wanted to know is this the actual server side logic or somethimg else?

Comment: The incomprehensible JS code is simply minified to reduce the size.

Answer (score 1):

This is the minimized version of jQuery which is just loaded there for further use,